# .html() jQuery function return NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<div id="tablePlace"></div>
```

And

```
if ($('#radioOne').is(':checked') == true) {
         $("#tablePlace").html(" ");
         $("#tablePlace").append(htmlTable); //htmlTable is a string that contains an html table code
         loadNestedTable(temp);
    }
```

It works but in the div I find NaN. 
If I comment `$("#tablePlace").append(htmlTable);`, NaN doesn't appear.

Why?

**UPDATE**

htmlValue code:

```
var tab = '<table id="decretoSingolo">'+
+'<thead>' 
+   '<tr>'
+       '<th>Ente</th>'
+       '<th>CUP</th>'
+       '<th>Decreto impegno</th>'
+       '<th>Data decreto impegno</th>'
+       '<th>Importo impegno</th>'
+       '<th>Finanziato MIUR</th>'
+       '<th>Importo pagato</th>'
+       '<th>Importo in pagamento</th>'
+   '</tr>'
+ '</thead>'
+   '<tbody>'
+   '</tbody>'
+'</table>'

+'<div style="display:none">'    
+   '<table id="dettagliDecretoSingolo">'
+   '<thead>' 
+           '<tr>'
+               '<th>Progressivo pagamento</th>'
+               '<th>Data decreto</th>'
+               '<th>Numero decreto pagamento</th>'
+               '<th>Tipo pagamento</th>'
+               '<th>Importo in pagamento</th>'
+               '<th>Nota decreto</th>'
+           '</tr>'
+       '</thead>'
+       '<tbody>'
+       '</tbody>'
+   '</table>'
+'</div>';
```

htmlTable value:

```
<table id="myTable">NaN<tr><th>Ente</th><th>CUP</th><th>Decreto impegno</th><th>Data decreto impegno</th><th>Importo impegno</th><th>Finanziato</th><th>Importo pagato</th><th>Importo in pagamento</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table><div style="display:none"><table id="myTableDetails"><thead><tr><th>Progressivo pagamento</th><th>Data decreto</th><th>Numero decreto pagamento</th><th>Tipo pagamento</th><th>Importo</th><th>Nota</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table></div>
```

NaN appears after .append(). There is a problem in the htmlTable code?

Comment: console.log the value of htmlTable variable

Comment: What is the value of `htmlTable`?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi: Or better yet, use the debugger and inspect it as the code runs.

Comment: `htmlTable` is not numeric value but could you please post from where it comes?

Comment: Hi guys, I update with htmTable value

Comment: You have `NaN` in your html how you expect from it to just disapear.

Comment: Problem with `htmlTable`. Please write code of `htmlTable`.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi, yes. But why?

Comment: @DavideFruci please check T.J Crowder's answer.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you have a unary `+` in your code:

```
   var tab = '<table id="decretoSingolo">'+
   +'<thead>' 
// ^--- Here
```

#### To fix it:

Remove one of the `+`s. Usually it's best to use the `+` at the end of the previous line, to avoid issues with automatic semicolon insertion.

#### Why you're getting `NaN`:

It's a unary `+` because it follows the `+` at the end of the previous line, with whitespace in-between them (so it's not `++` as I initially suggested).

That unary `+` will try to take its operand (the string that follows it) and convert it to a number, and if that can't be done will yield `NaN`. Then the operands to the `+` on the previous line are a string and a number, so that addition operator converts the string to number and adds it to `NaN` (which yields `NaN`).

You can see it here:

```js
var tab = '<table id="decretoSingolo">'+
+'<thead>' 
+   '<tr>';
document.body.innerHTML = tab;
```

---

Side note: There's no need to do `.html(" ")` and then `.append(htmlTable)`, just do `.html(htmlTable)`.

Comment: I'm very agree with "Usually it's best to use the + at the end of the previous line" . ^^

Answer (score 3):

You have double plus sign `+` in the following lines, remove one :

```
var tabellaDecretoSingolo = '<table id="decretoSingolo">'+
+'<thead>' 
+   '<tr>'
```

Should be :

```
var tabellaDecretoSingolo = '<table id="decretoSingolo">'
+'<thead>' 
+   '<tr>'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: why not directly $("#tablePlace").html(htmlTable); ?

Comment: Omg i had the same issue thank you very much, it made the trick

Comment: You're welcome, and I'm glad to see this answer helping after 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can optimise your javascript:

```
if ($('#radioOne').is(':checked') == true) {
     $("#tablePlace").html(" ");
     $("#tablePlace").append(htmlTable); //htmlTable is a string that contains an html table code
     loadNestedTable(temp);
}
```

by

```
if ($('#radioOne').is(':checked') == true) {
     $("#tablePlace").html(htmlTable); //html() replace all content of your element child. 
     loadNestedTable(temp);
}
```

Also, you've a problem when you define your "htmlTable" value

```
<table id="myTable">NaN<tr> [...]
```

check after your ">" of your  element if you don't add a NAN var...